# Visual Studio Build Event Immediately Return

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file

I have a somewhat long-running post-build event (long enough to be annoying to wait for but short enough to be finished after each release compilation) that I want to return immediately to VS.  I've tried to run batch files with `start` but visual studio still waits for the `cmd` window to close before returning success.

Is there a way to immediately return success when spawning this post-build event?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768358/how-to-create-an-asynchronous-build-event-in-visual-studio-2008) question seems to think that there is a way:

```
powershell start-process <actual-command-line-to-run>
```

Haven't tested it myself though.

Comment: Can confirm it works - just tested it out by adding a 'pause' command to a batch file - Compilation succeeds while the batch window blocks asking 'Press any key to continue'.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a batch file, you could try the `start` inside of the batch, or try to place it in the Post-build settings.

Inside of the batch

```
@echo off
if "%~1"=="async" goto :async
start "" "%~0" async %*
exit /b

:async
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing for a more direct answer that isn't a workaround, simply type "cmd" as the first line, followed by whatever commands you wish to use.